# Cloudant DB api supports pagination?

Tags: pagination, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

I have an app already using `cloudant.synch.query.IndexManager` to query the db. But I need pagination. I can see Cloudant supports it by using bookmark, but I can only find doc about using HTTP Post to url Path: `/db/_find`. the methods in `IndexManager` don't have bookmark. Is there an cloudant api I can use, instead of doing the http post?

My app is Android and iOS app that uses IBM Bluemix MobileFirst service as the back end. And I'm using bms_samples_android_bluelist (https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-bluelist)as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Skip and Limit for paging.

I got this from Cloudand Synch doc https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md

Skip and limit

Skip and limit allow retrieving subsets of the results. Amongst other things, this is useful in pagination.

skip skips over a number of results from the result set.
limit defines the maximum number of results to return for the query.
To display the twenty-first to thirtieth results:

QueryResult result = im.find(query, 20, 10, fields, null);
To disable:

skip, pass 0 as the skip argument.
limit, pass 0 as the limit argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! Cloudant's native mobile libraries for Android and iOS are dubbed "Cloudant Synch." Most of the resources there are compiled on this page: https://cloudant.com/cloudant-sync-resources/